# Tilting a specific section of non-uniform curve

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

I'm new to Blender and am trying to model a bracket for 3d printing.

I need to bend the highlighted section of the model. The lowest point of the bend should remain fixed and the elements connected to the top part of the bend should maintain their relationship.
.. I hope that makes sense..?

I have tried attaching the model to a mesh, as well as the 'simple deform > bend' modifier but so far either i'm doing it wrong, or these are the wrong tools.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I want to take this highlighted section of the model:

[image: Bend this]

And bend/lean it so that the top section tilts about 2mm to the right (the total hight of the model is 150mm)

[image: to here]

Thanks in advance!

GK

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is just by selecting the entire top section, moving your camera to the side view using 1, 3, or 7 on the number pad, and rotating with r and transforming with g. Other than that the only thing I can think of is rigging, which might be more trouble than it's worth in t his case.

Comment: Thanks Michael,

Comment: Thanks Michael,

The problem with rotate/move, is that the result is a straight line. Sorry, I should have been clearer in my original post; I need the highlighted section to be a smooth curve.